# IE driver tries to close new window instantly which opens after clicking on link while running on grid

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-11, selenium-grid

I m running a UI test in which IE 11 driver clicks on a link which opens a new window then it dose further test. this works as expected on my local machine but when I run this test in my remote desktop (selenium grid) IE driver instantly tries to close the new window and a alert for closing the window appears this is causing my test to fail. 
Can some one please enlighten me what is causing this behavior in IE while running on grid only. And how to solve this issue ?

thanks.....

Comment: it could be that the default setting for blocking popups is in action. check your settings on that. also, if there's an error that's not being trapped, then the driver may just crash out, closing everything in its wake.

Comment: no @jim I've disabled popup blocker. :)